# AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool and custom CALayer: setNeedsDisplay each frame?

Tags: objective-c, ios, video, core-animation, avfoundation

I'm using the `AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool` with a `AVAssetExportSession` to draw overlays into a video on iPhone.

particularly i'm looking to draw something really similar to Timecode into the video.  I can do this witha custom `CALayer` (or layer delegate, either way). I have this working with one issue,

The problem is I can't see a way of calling setNeedsDisplay each frame on my custom CALayer so that I can change the type every frame through the `drawInContext` call.

Is there someway to ensure that `drawInContext` is called before rendering each frame of the video during export?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you found an answer to this problem? I have the exact same issue related to question http://stackoverflow.com/q/7523541/913665 and so is John in http://stackoverflow.com/q/6022873/913665. Thanks for your help.